# How can I split values as int and string in column and calculate duration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe, there are several columns. One of them is based on time duration. While some of them is based on hours and others are based on minutes.

Like

```
2.5 hours
1 hours
41 minutes
42 hours
...
```

The column info is here

```
content_duration     3683 non-null   object
```

I want to convert all datas as minute values and their column are based on float or int type.

I wrote a function to perform this process but there is a problem to convert string to int.

How can I fix the issue?

Here is my code snippet shown below.

```
def convertminutes(column):
    value = column.str.split(' ').str[0].astype(float)
    timetype = column.str.split(' ').str[1]
    for i in range(len(timetype)):
        if timetype[i] == "hours" or timetype[i] == "hour":
            value[i] = value[i] * 60
        else:
            value[i] = value[i]        
    return value
```

I Called the function in this code shown below.

```
df["content_duration"] = convertminutes(df["content_duration"])
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: would you please share a few rows of your data?

Comment: @Hamid  I already shared some values in content_duration column.

Comment: would you show a column example like pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

def convert_to_minutes(x):
    return float(x.split()[0]) * 60 if 'hour' in x else float(x.split()[0])

df = pd.DataFrame({'content_duration': ['1 hour', '2.5 hours', '18 minutes','3 hours', '12 hours', '16 minutes', ]})
df['content_duration'] = df['content_duration'].apply(convert_to_minutes)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   content_duration
0              60.0
1             150.0
2              18.0
3             180.0
4             720.0
5              16.0
```

Comment: it throws an error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Beginner'

Comment: it throws an error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Beginner'

Comment: @TonyBrand can you share the data for which it getting the error

Comment: I shared a screenshot

Comment: @TonyBrand it's  working for me. any missing space can cause this error

Comment: I can only split this column by using df['content_duration'].str.split(' ').str[0] and str[1]

Comment: reason for the error your column contains `Beginner` as a value in some row

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

```
def convertminutes(column):
    map_dict = {"hours": 60, "hour": 60, "minute": 1, "minutes": 1}
    expanded_df = column.str.split(' ', expand=True)
    expanded_df[1] = copy_df[1].map(map_dict)
    return expanded_df[0].astype(float) * expanded_df[1]
```

Not the most efficient route, but it works.

Comment: it throws an error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Beginner'

Comment: This points that your data isn't as homogeneous as you're making it seem. You're going to have to do some cleanup before you can apply the changes you're wanting here.